# Do circular dependencies generally take a lot of time to compile?

Tags: c++, circular-dependency

**EDIT: Modified header files with guards. I forget to put those in this example. Although I already had those in my project.**

I have this two clases.

File a.h:

```
#ifdef A_H
#define A_H
#include "b.h"
#include "x.h" //not related to problem, is just included
class B; //fwd declaration, needed to use getB() outside of A
class A
{
public:
    A(X &x);
    B &getB();
    ...
private:
    X &x;
}
#endif
```

File b.h:

```
#ifdef B_H
#define B_H
#include "x.h"
class A; //fwd declaration
class B
{
public:
    B(X &x, A &a);
    void methodThatUsesA();
    ...
private:
    X &x;
    A &a;
}
#endif
```

File a.cpp:

```
#include "a.h"
#include "b.h"
A::A(X &x):x(x){}
B& A::getB()
{
    static B b(x, *this);
    return b;
}
...
```

File b.cpp:

```
#include "b.h"
#include "a.h"
B::B(X &x, A &a) : x(x), a(a){}
void B::methodThatRequiresA(){
    //does its thing...
}
```

From outside of them, I use them like this:

```
#include "x.h"
#include "a.h"
X x(...);
A a(x);
a.getB().methodThatRequiresA();
```

Resuming this, I have a class B that requires an object of class A to work, and A provides an object of type B that uses itself, via getB(), since there must be only an instance of B for each A, I though this was ok. Althrough the compile time increased a few seconds since I did this and I only have one more class in my project which is very little.

Do circular dependencies takes so long to compile? If so, it could be a lot time consuming compiling projects with lots of circular dependencies like this.

Comment: no, circular dependencies take no  more time than anything else.  The only things to keep an eye on are to many headers included in each cpp (use forward declarations) , and template metamagic.

Comment: Headers included in each cpp are actually needed. That's why I put the example code.

Comment: Adrian, my code at work compiles slowly.  When I actually measured it, each cpp was pulling in about 700 header files.  _Thats_ what slows it down.

Comment: How do you measure that? Do you use some command for that?

Comment: Visual Studio's compiler, and probably other compilers, has an option to list each header file as it's included in the build output

Answer (score 1):

Compiling big project, especially with optimization may take pretty long. But in your case culprit is that you do not use guards in your header and compiler has to parse the same header file multiple times. so solution could be (for file a.h):

```
#ifndef A_H_
#define A_H_
// 
//

#endif // A_H_
```

There are different solutions for this like pragma once from MS VS etc, but this is IMO most portable way. Symbol does not have to exactly like this, but must be unique.

Comment: Ok, I had those defines already I forget to put those in the example, sorry.